6D (2,0) theory
I am a beginning physics student, interested in learning the much coveted 6D (2,0) theory. I have heard this is an extended TQFT, with higher categorical structures like $(\infty,n)$ arising in it. Can someone kindly provide me some references to start with?

I’ve submitted an edit to your question to link to the relevant Wikipedia article. It provides seven references.

What do you mean by “a beginning physics student”. I would interpret this to mean that you’re in high school.

(2,0) is not a TQFT, but it is a CFT, a conformal field theory, which is a special and important class of QFTs. So CFT is definitely among the topics you should study to one day reach (2,0).

This theory is a non-Lagrangian strongly coupled QFT of non-abelian gerbes and dual to M-theory on AdS7.

This theory is a non-Lagrangian strongly coupled QFT of non-abelian gerbes and dual to M-theory on AdS7. Meaning that the understanding is very limited and fragmented. Here are some known results.
The gerbes are 2-form analogues of connection one-forms. There is no classical Lagrangian for such a theory so the theory is a QFT only and we lack a description due to our inability to understand strongly coupled phenomena in more than three dimensions. What is known is that the partition function is not a function but a section of a line bundle on the space of conformal blocks. This bundle is also called Schenker-bundle and this is analogue to the WZW-Story. If the rank of the group of the Lie algebra the gerbes take values in is 1 then we have a Lagrangian description. Additionally, we know its field content and symmetries because it is a CFT and there is a dictionary we can use. We can also partially twist this theory ala Witten on a product of a four-manifold and a Riemann-surface, which leads to the AGT-correspondence.
I would recommend nlab when looking for sources. If you want a nice introduction and some reasoning why it cannot have a classical description, my favourite is Witten: Geometric Langlands from six dimensions
